# Still bug in Integrate. 3

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, integral-transforms

Let us consider in version 13.1 on Windows 10

```
r = Integrate[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-(( 2 (ArcCot[(1 - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] -  ArcCot[(1 + a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]]))/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]), a > 1]`

Unfortunately, the above contradicts numerics:

```
r /. a -> 2
```

> `\[Pi]/Sqrt[3]`

, but

```
NIntegrate[1/(x - 2)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]
```

> `-1.8138`

That bug was submitted by me in February, 2018, when the output of `r`

> `ConditionalExpression[-((\[Pi] Abs[a])/(a Sqrt[-1 + a^2])),  a >= 1 || a <= 0]`

was incorrect too. Is there a workaround for `r`?

Comment: MMA v12.2 (Windows10) evaluates both integrals  correctly.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: Thank you. Therefore, this is a regression. What is the second one of your "both"?

Comment: `int[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann: That was OK in 2018.

Comment: This is a thorny problem. It came about due to a change in the antiderivative that in turn has a parametrized singularity that in turn gives `Limit` trouble. If one explicitly provides `Assumptions->a>1` then `Limit` will find the appropriate results as it approaches from each side of the parametrized singularity. But at the point where this computation occurs it instead has deduced `a<0||a>1` with the further stipulation `a>0` (thus `a>1`) arising later. With the conjunction it does not get the right limit, and fails to recognize this.

Comment: Mathematica correctly finds it for concrete values of `a`, for example, `Integrate[1/(x - 2)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: Just to compare. Maple 2022.2 produces short and correct (though somewhat  weird) result for the integral under consideration for all real `a`.

Answer (score 4):

Workaround:

```
$Version
(*"13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"*)
```

**I**

```
(*Works for: a > 1 || a < -1*)

r = InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[
MellinTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> {s > 0, a \[Element] Reals}], s, a] // Expand
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138*)
```

**II**

```
(*Works for: a > 1*)

r = LaplaceTransform[Integrate[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1},
Assumptions -> s > 0], s, a]
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138*)
```

**III**

```
(*Works for: a > 1 || a < -1*)

r = ZTransform[Integrate[
InverseZTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> Re[s] > 0], s, a] // FullSimplify
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138*)
```

**IV**

```
(*Works for: a > 1*)

r = (IntegrateChangeVariables[
 Inactive[Integrate][1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}], t, 
 t == x - a] // Activate)[[1]]
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138 + 0. I*)
```

**V**

```
(*Works for: a > 1 || a < -1*)

r = Sum[Integrate[
 SeriesCoefficient[1/(b*x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {b, 0, j}][[1, 1, 
   1]], {x, -1, 1}][[1]], {j, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138*)
```

**VI**

```
(*Works for: a > 1 *)

r = Integrate[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 1]
r /. a -> 2 // N
(*-1.8138*)
```

Comment: I am out of MMA at the present so I will give my  response later.

Comment: V. I begin from the end.  I see a mistake there: in `Sum[Integrate[
 SeriesCoefficient[1/(b*x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {b, 0, j}][[1, 1, 
   1]], {x, -1, 1}][[1]], {j, 0, Infinity}] ` the multiplier `b^j` is omitted. If you put `b==1`, then the convergence of the series at this point    must be grounded. My conclusion  - V fails. Thank you anyway.

Comment: IV.  It's clear that the change `t == x - a` does nothing. The command `Activate[
 IntegrateChangeVariables[
  Inactive[Integrate][1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}], t, 
  t == x - a]]` produces `ConditionalExpression[(2 I (ArcTanh[(-1 + a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] - 
      ArcTanh[(1 + a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]]))/Sqrt[-1 + a^2], 
 Re[(-1 - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] == 0 && 
  Re[(I - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] == 
   0 && (Re[a] < -1 || Re[a] > 1 || a \[NotElement] Reals)]`, The condition is omtted by you.  The condition  `Re[(I - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] == 0` is not valid for `a==2`. Conclusion - IV is a fake.

Comment: III. Saying nothing  about  that `ZTransform` is a discrete transform but you apply it  to any real `a` and the justification of the composition of the integral and the transforms (Can you kindly give a reference to such an approach? ), `ZTransform[
  Integrate[
   InverseZTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1}, 
   Assumptions -> Re[s] > 0], s, a] // FullSimplify` results in `-(\[Pi]/(Sqrt[1-1/a^2] a))` without any conditions on `a` so this is not true and reliable. Conclusion- III cannot be treated as a workaround.

Comment: II. Saying nothing  about  the justification of the composition of the integral and the transforms (Can you kindly give a reference to such an approach? I haven't seen such an approach in math literature.), `LaplaceTransform[
 Integrate[InverseLaplaceTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> s > 0], s, a]` results in `-((Pi^(3/2)*Piecewise[{{a/(Sqrt[-1 + a^2]*Sqrt[Pi]), a > 1}}, 
    0])/a)` which is not true for `a<=1`. Conclusion- II cannot be treated as a workaround.

Comment: I. Saying nothing  about  the justification of the composition of the integral and the transforms (Can you kindly give a reference to such an approach? I haven't seen such an approach in math literature.), 
 `InverseMellinTransform[ Integrate[   MellinTransform[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], a, s], {x, -1, 1},    Assumptions -> {s > 0, a \[Element] Reals}], s, a] // Expand` results in `-\[Pi]^(3/2) MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {1/4, 3/4}}, {{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}}, -a,
    1/2] + \[Pi]^(3/2)  MeijerG[{{0, 1/2}, {1/4, 3/4}}, {{0, 0}, {1/4, 3/4}}, a, 1/2]`, without any resrictions on `a`.

Comment: That is not true for `a>-1&&a<1`. Conclusion- I cannot be treated as a workaround.

Comment: Concerning V. `Sum[Integrate[
     SeriesCoefficient[1/(b*x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {b, 0, j}][[1, 1, 
       1]], {x, -1, 1}][[1]]*b^j, {j, 0, Infinity}] // FullSimplify` results in  `-(\[Pi]/(a Sqrt[1 - b^2/a^2]))` without any conditions on `a` and `b`. This is not true for `b==1` and `a==1/2`. Therefore, even the adjusted V cannot be treated as a workaround.

Comment: @user64494. Concerning V ,for a=1/2 integral is divergent.I add for all workarounds restrictions.Try: `Integrate[1/(x - 1/2)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]` ?

Comment: You wrote: "I add for all workarounds restrictions". The question arises: how do you derive those restrictions? Sorry, but all your "workarounds " are built on the sand. Your "workaround  IV"  was (and is) a fake.

Comment: The condition `Re[(I - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] ==     0` in IV is not valid for any real `a`, except `a==0` where the integral diverges.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work): I am still waiting for your reply to "Saying nothing about the justification of the composition of the integral and the transforms (Can you kindly give a reference to such an approach? I haven't seen such an approach in math literature.)". I believe civilized people use to answer requests

Comment: I don't reference to such an approach. My approach in math literature probably not exist, because is new .Wait for a better answer and just ignore my new age math.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work): I In this case think of its publication in a journal . Good luck! I repeat -- You wrote: "I add for all workarounds restrictions". The question arises: how do you derive those restrictions? Sorry, but all your "workarounds " are built on the sand. Your "workaround IV" was (and is) a fake. The condition `Re[(I - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] ==     0` in IV is not valid for any real `a`, except `a==0`, where the integral diverges.

Comment: All my workaround gives a correct answer: `-1.8138` so what is the problem?

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work): The question is: what's a workaround for `Integrate[1/(x - a)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, 
Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]`, not only for `a==2`. Sorry, you don't answer it. I repeat again -- You wrote: "I add for all workarounds restrictions". The question arises: how do you derive those restrictions? Sorry, but all your "workarounds " are built on the sand. Your "workaround IV" was (and is) a fake. The condition `Re[(I - a)/Sqrt[-1 + a^2]] ==     0` in IV is not valid for any real `a`, except `a==0`, where the integral diverges.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work):  Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need. BTW. MMA 13.1 on Windows 10 correctly finds `Integrate[1/(x - 2)/Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: @user64494 (1) Your claim that "@ does not work" is generally nonsense. If it's not working for you, find a new keyboard. (ii) Some or all of the claimed methods should follow from the [method of differentiating or integrating an integral with respect to a parameter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.01249.pdf). Roughly speaking, one has a pair of operators that commute because they operate with respect to distinct variables.

Comment: @user64494 you don't need to '@' the OP, Mariusz will be notified. Anyway, I am here because it was auto flagged with too many comments, I am not obliged to check maths here so let me ask, can we compile this discussion to a single comment or an edit with a disclaimer that presented workarounds have different 'assumptions'? With or without a response to that which confirms or denies it? DanielLichtblau what do you think?

Comment: @kuba I think condensing the count by merging comments would be fine. Or they could go into the response proper provided it is clear who wrote what. I see no prerogative for anyone to provide proofs of convergence regions (this not being math.se), though of course such further detail would be useful to have.